# java error: Could not find or load main class, but my code, java version, environmental variables all OKAY

Tags: java

I set all the paths correctly through 'environment variables' and my code is fine. 
It does compile my file, but it cannot run it. I'm a mathematician and normally run java files at uni, but this time I downloaded jdk on my window computer to work from home. Please could anyone help me?

paths in environment variable C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\bin

CLASSPATH in environment variable C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\lib

Both java and javac versions look fine.

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Algo> java -version
java version "1.8.0_231"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_231-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.231-b11, mixed mode)
PS C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Algo> javac -version
javac 1.8.0_231
PS C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Algo> javac HowAreYou.java
PS C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Algo> java HowAreYou
Error: Could not find or load main class HowAreYou
```

The following is my java code:

```
class HowAreYou {

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        System.out.print("Hello ");
        System.out.print(args[0]);
        System.out.println(", how are you today?");
    }

}
```

Comment: Delete the CLASSPATH environment variable. Use `java -cp . HowAreYou` (but `.` is the default if you stop defining CLASSPATH, so once you've deleted this env variable, then java HowAreYou should work)

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. However, it does not seem to work either. It gives this message: PS C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Algo> javac HowAreYou.java
PS C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Algo> java HowAreYou
Hello Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
        at HowAreYou.main(HowAreYou.java:5)

Comment: @Piemel The `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` is a totally different problem, which is explained on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554734/what-causes-a-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-and-how-do-i-prevent-it. In this specific case you have to provide an argument for the `java` call, like `java HowAreYou SomeNameHere`.

Comment: Of course, there must be an argument. Thank you again!

Comment: In the meantime, would it be possible to know why you told me to delete CLASSPATH? What's the logic behind it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do any of the following to make it work:

1. Remove the `CLASSPATH` from the environment variables > Close the current `cmd` window > Open a new `cmd` window > Run `javac HowAreYou.java` > Run `java HowAreYou Piemel`
2. Run `set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;.` > Run `javac HowAreYou.java` > Run `java HowAreYou Piemel`

Comment: Thank you for your reply! The first method gives the following error: Hello Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 whereas the second method gives PS C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Algo> set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;.
At line:1 char:27
+ set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;.
+                           ~
Missing expression after '.' in pipeline element.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRec
   ordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingExpression

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: I've asked the same question above, but could you tell me why I should delete CLASSPATH?